# emacs run shell command against current buffer's file name

Tags: vim, emacs

I just migrated from `vim` to `emacs` and I'm editing an `HTML` file now.

In `vim`, I can use `!firefox %` to open current file.

But in `emacs`, if I typed `M-!` then `firefox %f`, it uses firefox to open

```
http://www.%f.com/
```

page.

I tried `firefox (buffer-name)`, it doesn't work for me as well.

Could anyone tell me the expression which stands for the current file?

I found some similar questions, but the solutions are all about writing lisp function then use key bindings. I wish I could just use some kind of placeholder like `%f` within the shell command, and have it automatically expand to the buffer's filename when Emacs runs the command.

Comment: I believe I understand what you want to do, but I'm very confused about your references to "regex" in both the text and the tags. I can't see any use of regular expressions anywhere in this question.

Comment: If you have searched similar questions, you should link to them so that we can see what you've already looked at.

Comment: @philsThank you for your suggestions. I searched similar questions, I think it belongs to regex because I want to use "*,%,%s" these symbols to represent current filename.

Comment: @phils,I found a solution according to the similar question link. After M-!, I can use <down> key to get current filename.

Comment: Yes, that's a good way to do it. FYI regular expressions are for *matching patterns* in text, whereas you're describing using special place-holder tokens which automatically *expand* into particular values. They're two entirely different concepts. I shall edit the regex term out of the question...